# csv from URL to json file in node.js

Tags: json, node.js, csv

"New to programming"
I have a CSV file at
http://vhost11.lnu.se:20090/assig2/data1.csv

I am trying to convert it to a local json file. My code below.

I am getting `{"X":"153","Y":"21","time":"21438"}}` value in my `data1.json`.

```
const request=require('request')
const csv=require('csvtojson')
const fs = require('fs')
csv()
  .fromStream(request.get('http://vhost11.lnu.se:20090/assig2/data1.csv'))
  .on("json",function(jsonObj){ //single json object will be emitted for each csv line    
    console.log(jsonObj);
    fs.writeFile("./data1.json", JSON.stringify(jsonObj), (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return;
        };
    }); 
  });
```

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The callback function in the `on` event is called for each line.  You'll want to initialize an empty list in the outer most scope and push jsonObj to it from the callback in `on`.  You can then write your list to a file when the input file is done being read by handling the `done` event.